# Making Flask-AppBuilder play nicely with views of tables with multiple foreign keys

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-appbuilder

I have been playing around am using Flask-AppBuilder to build a simple CRUD
application.  The views work smoothly except for tables with multiple foreign key
relationships to the same table.  When I try to sort on a JOINed column, sqlalchemy
complains about a confusing relationship.

In this app we have *Child* which has a relationship to two *Adults*:

```
class Adult(Model):
    adult_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))

class Child(Model):
    child_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    adult1_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('adult.adult_id'))
    adult2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('adult.adult_id'))
    # We can also use foreign_keys to setup the relationships
    # This makes the view work (until you sort)
    adult1 = relationship("Adult", lazy='joined', backref='Adult1', primaryjoin='Adult.adult_id == Child.adult1_id')
    adult2 = relationship("Adult", lazy='joined', backref='Adult2', primaryjoin='Adult.adult_id == Child.adult2_id')
```

The view properly shows the name for each adult associated with the child

```
class ChildView(ModelView):
  datamodel = SQLAInterface(Child)
  list_columns = ['child_id', 'name', 'adult1.name', 'adult2.name']
```

But when we try to sort by the adult name we get a traceback:

```
InvalidRequestError: Could not find a FROM clause to join from.  Tried joining
to <class 'app.models.Adult'>, but got: Can't determine join between 'child'
and 'adult'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship
between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.
```

I can disable sorting on the columns by way of a workaround, but I would
really like to understand what I am missing.

The full code is here https://github.com/cwebber314/fab_multiple_fk

### Traceback

The full traceback on sort by `Adult1.name` or `Adult2.name`:

```
<snip irrelevant stuff here...>
File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\flask_appbuilder\views.py", line 475, in list
  widgets = self._list()
File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\flask_appbuilder\baseviews.py", line 877, in _list
  page_size=page_size)
File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\flask_appbuilder\baseviews.py", line 791, in _get_list_widget
  count, lst = self.datamodel.query(joined_filters, order_column, order_direction, page=page, page_size=page_size)
File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\flask_appbuilder\models\sqla\interface.py", line 94, in query
  query = query.join(model_relation)
File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2010, in join
  from_joinpoint=from_joinpoint)
File "<string>", line 2, in _join

File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\base.py", line 201, in generate
  fn(self, *args[1:], **kw)
File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2154, in _join
  outerjoin, full, create_aliases, prop)
File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2227, in _join_left_to_right
  self._join_to_left(l_info, left, right, onclause, outerjoin, full)
File "c:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2356, in _join_to_left
  "Tried joining to %s, but got: %s" % (right, ae))

InvalidRequestError: Could not find a FROM clause to join from.  Tried joining
to <class 'app.models.Adult'>, but got: Can't determine join between 'child'
and 'adult'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship
between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.
```

Comment: I met same issues, in a message view, which has receiver/sender foreign keys to the same user table. The console throws error: "Was unable to import app Error: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Message.receiver - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table."

Answer (score 0):

i think i had the same issue when some time ago and this works:

```
float_lenght = Column(Float)
fkey_lenght_unit = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('unitlist.id'))
unit_lenght = relationship("UnitList", foreign_keys=[fkey_lenght_unit])
float_width = Column(Float)
fkey_width_unit = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('unitlist.id'))
unit_width = relationship("UnitList", foreign_keys=[fkey_width_unit])
float_height = Column(Float)
fkey_height_unit = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('unitlist.id'))
unit_height = relationship("UnitList", foreign_keys=[fkey_height_unit])
```

so maybe try:

```
adult2_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('adult.adult_id'))
adult2 = relationship("Adult", foreign_keys=[adult2_id ])
```